# Deleting everything between two characters in richTextBox

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace lines in rich text box, here is an example of a line:

something@something2:something3

What piece code do I need to use for deleting everthing between "@"and ":", so it deletes only "something2" but leaves everything else?
Ive been experimenting with this code shown below, but without luck.

```
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "/@.*:/", "");
```

Comment: Does this work? `"(?<=@).*?(?=:)"`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for:

```
Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "(?<=@).*?(?=:)", "");
```

---

**Details**

```
(?<=@)    # lookbehind for '@'
.*?       # non-greedy match-all
(?=:)     # lookahead for ':'
```